# Calculate: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{ix}{n} \right)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{ix}{n} \right)^n = ? $

From $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n = e^x$ in the real case, my guess is that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{ix}{n} \right)^n = e^{ix} $.

I tried splitting the expression into real and imaginary parts, but it doesn't seem to help. Another approach I tried is to write $x=re^{it}$, without any success either.

Will be happy to hear your opinion on this one.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can also proceed as follows

$$ 1+\frac{ix}{n} =\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}}\;e^{i\theta_n} $$

with $\theta_n = \arctan \frac x n$ then

$$\left( 1+\frac{ix}{n} \right)^n = \left( \sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}}\;e^{i\theta_n} \right)^n =\left( \sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}} \right)^n e^{in\theta_n}\to 1\cdot e^{ix}$$

Comment: Thank you! Will you please elaborate on how did you arrive to the first equality? ($1+\frac{ix}{n} =\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}}\;e^{i\theta_n}$)

Comment: For any complex number $a+ib$ we have the exponential form $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta = \arctan \frac b a (\pm \pi)$.

Comment: You can also refer also to [polar form for complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane)

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!